# SwipeView without android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, swipe

Is there a way to implement swiping between action bar tabs without using android.support.v4.app lib? Using the lib will make redo most codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for the answer, but i just found this:
["ViewPager can use native API Level 11 fragments, though you may need to create your own PagerAdapter. Or, you can use ViewPager without any fragments, using just ordinary View or ViewGroup objects for the pages."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910874/2025799)
If you have found an example or a better way, i would like to hear from you, otherwise happy coding :)